# Kivy and behavioral test

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way to simulate user behavior with kivy? Something selenium-like?

Comment: I can't answer the question as much as it is "closed as primarily opinion-based", but here's a small example of selenium like testing for kiv y I developed https://github.com/eviltnan/kivy-autotesting-example